# How to increment a variable while each time test plan is executed in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario to run a test plan multiple times in a day, during the first  execution of my UDV sequence should be "xxxx-1". Subsequent execution within the day the UDV sequence should get incremented  like  "xxxx-2", "xxxx-3", etc. I tried by putting a Bean Shell Post processor with an if condition.

Need to run daily, run the test every four hour interval and reset the counter back to 1 at 5th execution.

Comment: You want it daily?

Comment: Need to run daily, run the test every four hour interval and reset the counter back to 1 at 5th execution

Answer (score 0):

The only way to store the variable between Test Plan executions is to write it into a file or a database table.

To do it with the file:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def file = new File('number')
   if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
       number = '1'
   }
   else {
       number = file.text
   }
   props.put('number', number as String)
   ```
3. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
4. Add a JSR223 Sampler to the tearDown Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def number = props.get('number') as int
   number++
   new File('number').text = number
   ```
5. You can refer the generated value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `xxx-${__P(number,)}` where required.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)