# how to increment the number in jmeter body whenever we run jmeter run

Tags: jmeter

i want to increment the batch number in my jmeter body whenever i run the jmeter run

say for example im running 1 request it should be like bleow

'batch_number_1_2022-09-27_1'

also if i run 2 request it would be , batch number remains the same for that run only counter changes fo as many request we trigger

'batch_number_1_2022-09-27_1'
'batch_number_1_2022-09-27_2'

now when i run the jmeter 2nd time again it should be like below(batch number should be incremented)

'batch_number_2_2022-09-27_1'

and so on like below for everytime when i trigger jmeter run

'batch_number_3_2022-09-27_1'
|
|
|
|
'batch_number_n_2022-09-27_1'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element or [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter), the first one generates an incremented number on each iteration, the latter one each time it's being called.

So if you amend your payload to look something like:

```
batch_number_1_2022-09-27_${__counter(,)}
```

you will get the incremented postfix

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response , 

now if you run the jmeter script again it will have same batch number below

batch_number_1_2022-09-27_1
batch_number_1_2022-09-27_2
batch_number_1_2022-09-27_3
and so on

for me number next to batch_number_ should be incremented for every jmeter run like below

batch_number_2_2022-09-27_1

again after sometime if i come back and try running jmeter , batch number should be incremented like below

batch_number_3_2022-09-27_1

which means every jmeter run batch number should be incremented

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376154/how-to-increment-a-variable-while-each-time-test-plan-is-executed-in-jmeter

this worked for me